# django paginated sitemap url pattern

Tags: django, pagination

The short question is: what is the url pattern for the paginated sitemap?

So, I have in urls.py:

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemaps_views.index, {'sitemap_url_name': sitemaps}),
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', sitemaps_views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

When I go `example.com/sitemap-detail.xml`,

..it works perfectly fine. I have a limit of 10 (to do the pagination). However, I have forgotten how I move to the next page. I have tried:

`example.com/sitemap-detail-1.xml`, `example.com/sitemap-detail/1.xml`,

and they dont work.

Shortly speaking, which url do I need to access to move to the next page of the sitemap?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `?p=2` to the end of the URL gives me what I want.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect to next pages by using below URL pattern

```
example.com/sitemap-detail-1.xml
```